# Manually validate form using jquery.unobtrusive validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

I am currently developing a form with calculated totals. The value in field C for example, would be generated from the input items entered into Field A and Field B.

```
Field A - 10,
Field B - 20
Field C - 30
```

Field C has some validation on it to be less than a certain value. I am using the DataAnnotations library in MVC and I have hooked up the jquery.unobtrusive library to apply the validation on the client. I also picked up the following bit of code to display an error icon for each of the fields that error.

```
$(function () {
    $('form').each(function () {
        var validator = $(this).data('validator');
        validator.settings.showErrors = onValidated;
    });

function onValidated(errorMap, errorList) {
    $.each(errorList, function () {
        onError($(this.element), this.message);
    });

    if (this.settings.success) {
        $.each(this.successList, function () {
            onSuccess($(this));
        });
    }
}

function onSuccess(inputElement) {
    var fieldId = getElementFieldName(inputElement);
    var error = $("#" + fieldId + "Error").hide();
    error.attr('title', '');
}

 function onError(inputElement, message) {
        var fieldId = getElementFieldName(inputElement);
        var error = $("#" + fieldId + "Error").show();
        error.attr('title', message);
    }
```

This shows or hides the icon for the element selected - so if I enter an incorrect value into Field A then it will validate it accordingly and display an icon with the error message.

I am not sure of the best way of doing this, but I thought that maybe validating all of the fields after an entry would be the best idea- then if Field A is updated, then Field C is checked.

I am also looking for a point at which I can wire up the method to check for any errors - at the moment I can do this by looking for any icons - but I can't see a good point to wire this in so that it runs once rather than for each field.

Comment: https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations  this will do all those thing it is bit easy to implement.

Comment: You don't need to write customize jQuery validation for this thing.Only Attribute on Column need.That will also put jQuery validation.

Comment: Hi Parth - sorry, I don't understand your comment about 'Attribute on Column'. Could you expand this for me please?

Comment: Default dataannotations (entityframwork) has some of limits to put validation.So i use ExpressiveAnnotations. It allows any values (entity coulumn) ">" (greater than) "<" (less than) particular value and many more validations at C# side. So we don't have to put jquery.unobtrusive validation manually . Please check link i provided.